# can't create user on mysql on windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I just installed MySQL Version 8.0.27 on my windows machine, whenever i try to run MySQL command i get this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

and when i try to run MySQL -u root -p i get this error after specifying password

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Also i can't locate my.ini file. i was thinking if i should add my.ini file manually or download another version of mysql

Comment: Try `mysql -u root` without `-p`. Sometimes newly installed MySQL instances don't have root passwords (yet). They certainly don't have ODBC users in them yet.

Comment: Did you try `mysql -u root -p` and then just press enter when the password is requested?

Comment: yes i tried mysql -u root -p and it gives same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by installing mysql version  5.6.11

Comment: You will be very disappointed with `MySQL 5.6.11` version